# Calling a method only when another is finished using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to execute 2 methods during a ngOnInit(), but the method2() must be executed only when the method1() is completely finished. I'm not doing HTTP requests, both methods belong to the same component.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.method1();
    this.method2(); //need to be executed only when method1() is finished
  }

  method1() {
    //do something
  }

  method2() {
    //do something but need to be started only when method1 is finished
  }
```

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: If you don't execute any asynchronous operation then this is the default behaviour...

Comment: if it's asynchronous you can call the second method in first method callback

Comment: So, even if the method1 executes more complexes tasks the method2 will start only when the 1 finish?

Comment: Of course, if it contains synchronous code, even if it takes forever (say an infinite loop), it will block the rest of the code forever

Comment: Oh ok, I've been thinking that javascript is always asynchronous ... thanks your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fully works. If you don't execute any asynchronous operation then executing one function, statement, and expression after the other is the default behaviour...

Even when you call an asynchronous operation, all remaining statements and expressions are still executed in a synchronous fashion, until the end of the call stack is reached. The asynchronous operation is put onto the event loop to be executed at a later time.

Examples of asynchronous operations are not only HTTP calls, but also `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

You can read more about the event loop [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Answer (score -3):

If they don't execute async operations, why don't you just call the `method2` inside the `method1` after its own operations?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.method1();
}

method1() {
  //do something

  //completed running method1 operations so call this.method2 now
  this.method2();
}

method2() {
  //do something but need to be started only when method1 is finished
}
```

Comment: There's no reason why this would be better than putting them both in `ngOnInit`. This answer misleads the asker into thinking this is required to achieve what he wants, which is not the case.

Comment: @DavidWalschots Two questions. 1. how does this mislead the asker? The answer is offered as "why don't you", which is clearly asking the OP whether he has already considered this option or not. It's not answering as this is "the only way".

2. Given the information, this is CLEARLY one of the better ways to execute `method2` after executing the `method1` operations.

Comment: You're not telling the asker that his code also works. I don't see why this is _clearly_ the better way :-). Maybe `method1` and `method2` are unrelated, in which case calling 2 from 1 is not better.

Comment: Again, I don't understand how this is misleading at all when it's read as one of the possible options out there. Based on the information given, method2 should follow method1. As such, it's likely they are related. With the approach I posted, you don't have to juggle two separate methods so that, if you make any changes in the future, the relationship will be kept.

Comment: Those considerations are not part of the question. The question is what needs to be changed to make both functions execute one after the other. The answer is _nothing_.

Comment: You asked why I thought this is better. That's why I answered. And yes, they are not a part of the original concern. But again how does it mislead? Where is the false or inaccurate information given in the answer I provided?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179931/discussion-between-jsdriller-and-david-walschots).